# ¿Como manipular archivos .h en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, vscode, librería, codeblocks, headers

estoy aprendiendo C y hoy me explicaron como separar las funciones/procedimientos del archivo main en lo que seria un archivo .h para el encabezado, y un .c para la estructura. La cuestión es que lo explicaron en CodeBlocks y entendí como se hace todo, pero yo utilizo Visual Studio Code y a la hora de realizarlo ahí no me lo toma. Googleando encontré la extensión "EPITECH C/C++ Headers", la cual genero en el archivo .h algo parecido a lo que tengo en CodeBlocks (la verdad no tengo idea de que son los #ifndef y todo eso, por el momento no me lo explicaron). Pero sigue dando el mismo error, no se si estoy utilizando mal esta extensión, si necesito otra, si se hace de otra forma. Adjunto imagenes de lo que tengo en CodeBlocks y lo que hice en Visual.

[image: Esto es lo que tengo realizado en CodeB y quiero hacer en VSC]

[image: Esto es el main del VSC]

[image: Esto es el .h en VSC]

[image: Esto es el .c en VSC]

Comment: Hace tiempo tuve un error parecido, lo que hice fue poner todos mis archivos en el mismo directorio y compilar así `g++ *.c` Espero te funcione.

Comment: Creo que lo que pasa es que el archivo .h está malo, intenta copiar el contenido del archivo .h en uno .c e intenta compilarlo, si no da error esta bueno, de lo contrario no. Si el .h estuviera malo intenta corregirlo. Por otro lado, recuerda que los header se ponen entre comillas cuando están en el mismo directorio que el .c main. Verifica que los .h estém en en el mismo directorio que el .c. Saludos

Comment: No se que es lo del "g++ *.c", eso es para ejecutar desde cmd?.
Con respecto a lo de pasar el .h a un .c. Me da este error "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" pero la verdad no se que deberia de hacer, deberia de compilar sin problema?. Si es asi, no se que problema tengo que corregir

Comment: @JuliBlues No es un error de compilación como tal, simplemente el enlazador (o *linker*) no encuentra las funciones y por eso no genera el ejecutable final. Lo más probable es que solo estés compilando el `main.c`, debes indicarle al compilador que también compile `funciones.c`..

Comment: @MrDave1999 Claro entiendo, pero como le indico eso? lo de que compile el funciones también

Comment: @JuliBlues ¿Cómo le indicaste al compilador para que compile `main.c`?

Comment: @MrDave1999 Tengo la extensión de Code Runner, simplemente le doy al boton del play. No se si hay otra manera que pueda utilizar

Comment: La verdad nunca he utilizado el editor VSC, pero debes buscar la manera de configurar el comando en el editor, por ejemplo, este es el comando que deberías usar: `gcc -o exe main.c funciones.c`, esto crea un ejecutable llamado `exe`, aunque solo funciona si ambos archivos están en la misma carpeta..

Comment: @MrDave1999 Sisi, tengo todo en la misma carpeta. Ahora, ese comando donde va? O en otro IDE donde se colocaría? Perdón todas las preguntas jajaja, pero recién arranco en la carrera y no vi nada de eso

Comment: Tendrás que esperar una respuesta de alguien que usé VSC y sepa compilar ahí. Pero hasta mientras puedes ver esto: [Compilar y debuggear C y C++ en Visual Studio Code](http://holanerd.net/programacion/2019/11/02/compilar-c-y-cplusplus-en-visual-studio-code.html).

Comment: @MrDave1999 Perfecto, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que encontré la solución lo dejare por si le sirve a alguien. Lo más "fácil" que encontré es incluir en el main el archivo source como si fuera una librería más solo que con las comillas (como el header).

[image: source en el main]

De esta forma, si se tiene la extensión "Code Runner" y habilitado para que lo ejecute en la terminal debería ejecutar sin ningún problema.

Investigando un poco más y moviendo configuraciones llegué a otra conclusión que me gusta un poco más dado que no se incluye el .c en el main de esa manera, como contra hay que hacer unos pasos mas.

Tenemos que crear un "workspace" o "espacio de trabajo", básicamente una carpeta. Se puede hacer a mano, pero recomiendo usar la herramienta de Visual. Para eso tenemos que dar en Archivo -> Nueva ventana -> Agregar área de trabajo... De esta manera nos debería de quedar algo tal que así:

[image: área de trabajo]

Desde ahí mismo tenemos la opción de crear archivos por ende nos debería de quedar algo tal que así:

[image: Archivos ya creados]

Luego apretando la tecla F1 se nos debería desplegar una ventana donde podremos escribir. Ahí pondremos "task" o "tarea" en español y seleccionaremos la primera opción. Después daremos en "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file".

[image: generar .json]

Una vez realizado esto se nos va a crear un archivo .json, acá hay que hacer 2 cosas.

Para hacerlo un poco mas intuitivo (mas adelante vamos a ver donde) podríamos poner "build" donde dice "label:", tal que quede de esta forma: "label": "build",
Si eso no se hace no pasa nada, pero ya digo, para estar un poco mas ordenado es mejor hacerlo.

Ademas tendremos que agregar nuestro archivo .c en la parte de "args", abajo de "${file}",. Tal que todo el .json nos quede de esta manera:

[image: .json creado]

Yo uso MinGW y esta instalado predeterminado, si ustedes no, tienen que modificar la ruta.

Y listo, luego tendríamos que ir al main, pulsar las teclas "Ctrl + Shift + B" y se nos va a desplegar una ventana que contiene la opción "build" (eso es lo que cambiamos en "label"). Le damos ahí y nos generaría en la carpeta del principio un .exe. Cabe aclarar que no se puede usar el CodeRunner de esta manera pero así quitaríamos el "funciones.c" del main dejando solo el "funciones.h".

Espero les sea de ayuda y funcione!.

Comment: La respuesta no es correcta. Incluir un .c en el main es un error. Pero lo soluciona si no se hace uso de ese fichero desde ningún otro. Con que se haga otro include en otro punto saltarán referencias duplicadas por todos lados.

Comment: Sisi, por eso aclare la manera correcta de hacerlo, pero para salir del paso sirve. Gracias por el aporte igual!

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es muy sencilla. El compilador solo compila el fichero `main.c`, el `#include "funciones.h"` lo que hace es pegar ese fichero (con las declaraciones o prototipos de las funciones que están implementadas en el fichero `funciones.c`) en el `main.c`.

Entonces se genera un fichero de código objeto, `main.o`, que contiene solamente referencias a las declaraciones y prototipos de `funciones.h`, pero que están sin implementación.

Como no compilas el fichero `funciones.c`, no se genera un fichero objeto `funciones.o` con la implementación de las funciones a las que hace referencia el `main.o`.

Por todo esto, el `linker` no puede generar el ejecutable final a partir de los ficheros objeto.

Lo único que tienes que hacer es compilar tanto el `main.c` como `funciones.c`, para que el `linker` pueda enlazar las definiciones apuntadas en el `main.o` con las implementaciones compiladas en `funciones.o`.

```
gcc -o main main.c funciones.c
```

Esto compila el `main.c` y el `funciones.c`, y el `linker` puede enlazar los ficheros objeto resultantes en un solo ejecutable.

Por tanto, para próximos proyectos, recuerda que hay que compilar todos los ficheros `.c`, incluyendo el `main.c`, ya que el `#include` solo copia las cabeceras en el `main`, no su implementación.